# How do I correctly measure the circumference of a circle

Tags: circles, pi

I found [How exactly do you measure circumference or diameter?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549065/how-exactly-do-you-measure-circumference-or-diameter) but it was more related to how people measured circumference and diameter in old days.

**BUT** now we have a formula, but the value of PI cannot not be accurately determined, how can I find the accurately calculate the value of circumference of a circle?

Is there any other may be physical mean by which I can calculate the correct circumference?

thank you

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You mean really physically measure the length of a circle? Or you mean mathematically?

Comment: Actually both the ways.

Comment: Well mathematically you can determine $\pi$ with the precision you want! Take for example the serie $\pi^2/6=1/1^2+1/2^2+1/3^2+...$. You can use it to calculate $\pi$ as precise as you want...

Comment: And check here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi for even more methods on how to approximate $\pi$.

Comment: "accurately calculate" is one of those funny terms.   We have the ability to give you $\pi$ to any decimal place you want, accurately.   So, specify a precision and we can give you an answer within that error.

Comment: You don't have to measure the circumference by measuring the diameter and multiplying by $\pi$.  You can get a tape measure and measure the circumference directly.  If you're measuring something like a column or a tree trunk, this is much the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @Alan: "accurately" is definitely a funny one, but let me rephrase the question with "correctly or exactly".

Comment: An irrational real number can have a decimal sequence given by a "simple" formula: Any formula that is not periodic. E.g. if $x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}10^{-n^2}$  then the $10^{100}$-th decimal digit of $x$ is $1$. At present, no "simple" (a vague term) formula is known for $\pi$.  But  $\pi d$ IS the exact circumference.

Answer (score 2):

We can pretend to measure the circumference of a circle by saying 
circumference = $\pi$ * diameter

Since $\pi$ itself is an approximation, a "measurement" of the circumference will always and forever be just an approximation and NEVER an exact number.  It is quite interesting because one can clearly see a circle has bounds unlike a straight line which can be measured but can go on forever but a circle does not.

Quite mind boggling.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to the question what the circumference of a circle with diameter $d$ would be $\pi \cdot d $. Of course this is not a satisyfing answer. But since this ridiculous number $\pi$ cannot even be described by the root of a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$ we can only approximate $\pi$. This is not a bad thing though. For most, if not all, applications we can approximate $\pi$ good enough so we don't realize it is an approximation. For pure mathematics, we can just use the symbol ''$\pi$''

I hope this helps you a bit

Answer (score 0):

Construct the circle of diameter 1/pi.
The circle has circumference =1.
It’s sure exact value.
(You don't escape from pi - it's property of each circle).

Comment: This question already has some nice answers. You have not provided anything new in answering this old question. There are many unanswered questions which you are encouraged to aattempt